# vs code - inactive code highlighting

Tags: visual-studio-code

language : c++
extension: "C/C++ ms-vscode.cpptools V0.9.3"

**How can I setup highlighting of code that has been deactivated via a #ifdef in vs code.**
vscode is not highlighting/greying-out by default and I can't find a way to activate it.

Answer (score 6):

If you have "C/C++" extension installed on VS Code, it inactivates unused regions in the code. To fix this, go to extensions (Ctrl + Shift + X) -> "C/C++" -> click on the gear (next to the extension description) -> extension settings.

A file will show up. Look for the option "Dim Inactive Regions" and uncheck it.

You're done.

Answer (score 1):

You can now do that! Feb 2018 update for C/C++ extension added that feature: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cppblog/visual-studio-code-cc-extension-feb-2018-update/

Answer (score 1):

in the visual studio go to extension details then go to setting of this extension ms-vscode.cpptools and enable setting for highlighting inactive section there are total 48 settings u can search for inactive.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that. Syntax highlighting in Visual Studio Code is currently performed exclusively by grammar files based on regular expressions.

In order to highlight deactivated code an extension needs to alter the text appearance based on your current setup. Unfortunately there is no API available for that.

You can vote for that feature here: [Provide an API for advanced source highlighting](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/585)

Comment: Not entirely true: while indeed the highlighting is based on textmate theme files it goes further, you can also specify values in a json file.

Comment: @MikeLischke I'm not sure what you mean with "values in a json file". Do you have an example? You're not talking about something like that, do you? https://github.com/Wosi/vs.language.objectpascal/blob/master/objectpascalDef.js

Comment: Well, actually this: https://github.com/mike-lischke/vscode-antlr4/blob/master/syntaxes/antlr.json. Syntax elements defined in a json file. I find that much easier to read, hence I used json.

Comment: Thanks, I thought the support for that format was dropped in version 1.0 in favour of TextMate grammar files. I personally prefer the JSON format too. I edited the answer. Thanks for pointing this out.